# How to freeze my app WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to freeze my app WinForm while the `await` is running? But i want not use Form.Enabled = false, because this change the style of the WinForm (white opacity)

```
private async void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Freeze app
        await operation();
        // Unfreeze app
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need BtnOk_Click to be async, make it synchronous, otherwise, create a new Task and call Task.Wait or just call operation().Result if this will not cause deadlock in your case. If you are already not in UI thread, find a way to access UI thread. In WPF it's done with Dispatcher, don't know about Win Forms.

Comment: If you want to freeze you application, make synchronous calls instead of async/await...

Comment: Can you work on your other question?  It seems like you are spamming us with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use async/await, then your app will be frozen.  I presume `operation` is async, so you'll need to get the result.

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
     var result = operation().Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //
    }
}
```